# How to recognise two finger panning on trackpad?

Tags: macos, flutter

I see that the `SingleChildScrollView` allows scrolling via the MacBook trackpad with two-finger-panning.

However, I cannot find any gesture recogniser that is triggered by two-finger-panning.

How is two-finger-panning implemented for `SingleChildScrollView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. `Scrollable` listens to `PointerScrollEvent`.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/b007a81ad498eb9b7cd687fda0aa9d8d2bb77dc3/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable.dart#L642

However, there is no reliable way to detect when scrolling actually ended and is not just idle (the user lifted the fingers).